# Visual Studio Community 2015 - can't see emulator or device for 8.1 mobile

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk

I've got a little problem with Visual Studio Community 2015. I uninstalled it few weeks before, and reinstalled it yesterday; I've got the Update 1.
I tried to launch a Windows Phone 8.1 project, and I got the following error:

[image: error]

In the debug mode, I only got the option "Start" : I can't see my device (I used to before uninstalling), and can't see an emulator neither:

[image: menu]

If I deploy it manually, nothing fail, but nothing succeed...

I think my installation includes all that it needs...

[image: menu]

My phone is registered.

Any idea what's wrong? Thank you!

**EDIT :** uninstalled all the SDK's and emulators, repaired VS, rebooted, reinstalled SDK's and emulator, it now works... With 15Gb more on my sdd..

Strange thing is that I've got Windows 10 emulator for Win Phone 8.1 projects, and that the emulator are not available if I chose an ARM CPU, but ONLY for Windows Universal Apps... Don't know if it's normal (I'm very knew to this kind of development), but I'll see if that matters when I'm coding :D

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you try "Repair" option?

Comment: Not yet... I will try that!

Comment: So: the "Repair" thing fixed the emulator issue for 8.1... But now I can't load a universal solution / project, because the Windows 10 SDK is not found... I will uninstall / reinstall it and see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Right click solution -> choose properites -> click common properties in the dialog box -> in the startup project choose your windows phone 8.1 project. Done! (Y)